# Can we create Route53 traffic policies through CloudFormation or Terraform in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, terraform, amazon-route53

Is there a way to create traffic policies through CloudFormation or Terraform in AWS?

I find resource for creating hosted zones and record sets, but I want to create a traffic policy to route my traffic 50% and 50% in different regions.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no support from Terraform or CloudFormation for AWS Route 53 Traffic Policies:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_Route53.html
- https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11256

As a workaround you can save your policies as JSON files and use AWS-CLI to import them. And also you will need the AWS-CLI to associate them as this neither is possible (https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1159).

Traffic Policy Document Format: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/api-policies-traffic-policy-document-format.html

Comment: To add to this, it's a BIG workaround, instead of using Route 53 Traffic Policies use AWS Global Accelerator.
More info here: 
https://mxx.news/aws-global-accelerator-compared-to-cloudfront-and-route53/
https://cloudonaut.io/review-aws-global-accelerator-latency-multi-region-disaster-recovery/
This may not accomplish all the use cases but it's supported by Terraform: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/globalaccelerator_accelerator.html

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS CloudFormation Resource Types Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html) does not have an entry for Route 53 traffic policies.

There are API calls to CRUD the traffic policies, so it could be done via a Lambda Custom Policy.

Comment: Thank You, I will look into that option

Answer (score 0):

Terraform's [`aws_route53_record` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html) supports [weighted traffic policies](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html#weighted-routing-policy) to allow you to send a percentage of traffic to different targets.

If you are wanting to send traffic from different geographical regions to different targets then you can also use the [`geolocation_routing_policy`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html#geolocation_routing_policy) or [`latency_routing_policy`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html#latency_routing_policy).

If you'd prefer to use Cloudformation then weighted record sets are also supported by the [`AWS::Route53::RecordSet`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html) resource by using the `Weight` parameter. This Cloudformation resource also supports geolocation and latency based routing.